# Open Terminal Window after displaying an image through JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, terminal, bluej

I am displaying an image using JFrame, and the code written is to make the JFrame window to close after 5 seconds and open the Terminal window again. (You know, System.out.println(" blahblahblah ");)
Here's my code :

```
public static void closeCall()
{
    Long exitTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() + 5 * 1000;
    for(int i=1; i>0; i++)
    {
        Long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
        if (currentTime >= exitTime)
        {
            JFrame1.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(JFrame1, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            break;
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm on BlueJ 3.1.5 and JDK 8u40, and still learning stuff the trial and error way, so, umm, help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to open `cmd.exe` on Windows through Java code?

Comment: Nope. BlueJ Terminal Window. BTW @ShrinivasShukla System.out.println usually does the job and opens BlueJ Terminal window, but it doesn't work when I use Swing and AWT.

Comment: What the heck is the point of designing an app. that works in a single IDE?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's for a school project. Hell, this isn't going to be made into a JAR file at all. Just to submit for a school project, you know, with the arrays, for, while and do-while loops, etc. and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about BlueJ Terminal Window, but if you want to perform an Action after a certain time interval then you should be using a `Swing Timer` instead of creating a loop which will hog the CPU and make the frame unresponsive.

The Timer will simple fire an event after 5 seconds and then you close the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use Swing Timers for more information and examples.

Comment: I'm using a for loop cause my school teacher asks us to use it. I would've preferred Swing timers if it were up to me.